# What should we do when encountering wiki excerpt suggestions on useless tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

In review I got a suggestion for a wiki excerpt, the proposal in itself was not bad (https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/511060) but the tag [bible](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/bible) is quite useless, it has only one question and should be purged in my opinion.

I rejected the suggestion but want some community input on the general case.

Comment: I would accept it, If I have enough rep

Comment: Bible on AskUbuntu, i don't think they even care about each other and they don't go hand in hand.

Answer (score 11):

I'd say to reject the suggestion and to get rid of the tag.

Creating / editing a tag wiki excerpt for a tag that has no reason to exist puts the cart before the horse, and shouldn't be encouraged: much like useless edits it wastes reviewers' time for no benefit, since the tag is to be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Two things would be nice:

1. Remove that particular tag as this has wasted the time of the person who submitted the edit (me in this particular case) *as well as* the time of the reviewer.
2. Conduct a thorough review of the available tags and remove those tags that are in a similar position. This would save everybody a lot of time and energy.

A quick look through the tags currently available shows quite a few that could safely be removed. A solid criteria for such removal would need to be in place though...